# Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object in /source on line 20

Tags: php, mysql

This is my class, the error occurs on with this statement:

```
if($stmt = $this->conn->prepare($query))
```

I'm not entirely sure why I cannot prepare the query like this.  The function gets passed a username and password from a form on the login.php page.  I know that a connection is being made to the db because that's the problem I was working on all day.

```
<?php

require_once 'includes/constants.php';

class Mysql{
  private $conn;

function _construct() {
    $this->conn = new mysqli(DB_SERVER, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME) or 
                  die('Could not connect to database.');
}

//connect to database and return true if they're in there
function verifyUsernamePassword($un, $pwd){
    $query = "SELECT * 
            FROM users
            WHERE username = ? AND password = ?
            LIMIT 1";

    if($stmt = $this->conn->prepare($query)) {
        $stmt->bind_param('ss', $un, $pwd);
        $stmt->execute();

        if($stmt->fetch()) {
            $stmt->close();
            return true;
        }
    }
    else
        die('cannot touch database');

 }
}
```

If you need any other code please let me know, I just need any sort of fresh eyes to look at this.

Comment: Missing an underscore: `_construct` <-

Comment: `new mysqli` can never return a boolean false. ALL object instantiations can never return anything but the object being requested. you need to check `mysqli_connect_error()` instead.

Comment: @Rizier123 you're my hero